# Поведение EOF в C

Tags: c, файлы

Мне нужно было написать функцию для измерения величины файла в байтах. Вот, что вышло:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t file_size(char *file_path) {
    FILE *file = fopen(file_path, "rb");
    uint64_t size = 0;
    for (; fgetc(file) != EOF; size++);
    fclose(file);
    return size;
}

int main() {
    printf("%llu\n", file_size("file"));
    return 0;
}
```

Всё работает корректно. Потом мне стал интересен `EOF`. Ведь это просто константа, равная `-1`. Что, если файл будет содержать байт `-1` (То есть `FF`)?

Я написал программу, создающую файл из трёх байт, каждый их которых - `FF`.

`fputc(-1, file); fputc(-1, file); fputc(-1, file);`

Перепроверил hexdump'ом, что файл действительно содержит 3 байта (`FF FF FF`).

Дальше проверил размер файла с помощью функции, код которой я написал в самом начале. Вернула функция корректный размер - 3 байта.

Я изменил цикл в функции с

`for (; fgetc(file) != EOF; size++);`

на

`for (char c = fgetc(file); c != EOF; c = fgetc(file), size++);`

Проверил ещё раз - функция стала возвращать размер файла 0, потому что первый же байт равен `EOF`, то есть константе конца файла. Объективно, функция должна работать так же, как работала. Что не так? Как это работает? Как вообще константа конца файла EOF может быть равна одному из байт в файле? Кто это придумал? Может, я что-то упустил? Я 10 раз всё проверил. Магия.

Comment: Вас не смущает, что в новой реализации вы читаете из файла 2 раза подряд?

Comment: @becouse, нет такого.

Comment: Просто потому, что char не способен хранить значение EOF.

Comment: char - это не то же самое, что signed char или unsigned char. Он может быть как знаковым, так и беззнаковым, в зависимости от реализации. Но это не имеет значения. Если необходимо хранить не символы, а однобайтовые целые числа, то signed/unsigned нужно указывать явно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `fgetc` возвращает int, т. е. EOF - это не 0xFF, а 0xFFFFFFFF (ну или 0xFFFF на 16-битных платформах). Очевидно, что такое значение в байт не лезет, а жначит и в файле содержаться не может.

Есть нюанс, что вроде бы стандарт допускает равенство размеров char'а и int'a. Но лично я о таких платформах не слышал, так что не могу сказать, что там на эту тему.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641375/is-it-possible-to-confuse-eof-with-a-normal-byte-value-when-using-fgetc

Comment: EOF - это просто любое целое число, которое не может содержаться в файле. А char может содержать только допустимые символы. Об этом говориться в K&R, кстати.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον, оно должно быть отрицательным по стандарту.

Answer (score 2):

По стандарту:

- `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`
- `fgetc` возвращает тип `int`, но при этом значение может быть либо в диапазоне типа `char`, если очередной байт удалось считать, либо константой `EOF`, если если нет. Значение константы не попадает в диапазон `char`, если не путаю, равно -1.

Таким образом ваш пример

```
for (char c = fgetc(file); c != EOF; c = fgetc(file), size++)
```

некорректен, т.к. сравнение значения char 0xFF с int -1 (EOF) возвращает истину (по правилам расширения знаковых типов). На платформе с бесзнаковым char вы получите бесконечный цикл.

В примере же

```
fgetc(file) != EOF
```

`fgetc(file)` возвращает `0x00FF`, т.е. знаковое +255, которое не равно -1

**UPD** на комментарий от Qwertiy

В ответе по вышей ссылке есть ссылка на стандарт, в котором говорится, что:

1. `sizeof(char) == 1`
2. `short` минимальный диапазон -32768 … 32767.
3. `int`:

   - минимальный диапазон -32768 … 32767
   - по возможности, обрабатывается процессором за одну команду

Случай `sizeof(char) == sizeof(short)` возможен только на платформах, где байт 16 бит. Такая экзотика встречается крайне редко.

Случай `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)` возможен только если процессор имеет команды только для 16-битных чисел.

А `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)` только на архитектуре, где одновременно и байт 16 бит и нет 32-битных команд. Процессоры общего назначения такого типа не встречаются более 30 лет, да и микроконтроллеры крайне редки.

Так что да, теоретически, `sizeof(char)` может быть равен `sizeof(int)`, но это слишком маловероятно.

На практике встречается ситуации с `sizeof(char) < sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int)`

Comment: _`sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`_ - точно `<`, а не `<=`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29748444/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не ответ, но вариант поиска конца файла.

Вот минимальный пример получения размера файла в С. Циклы не нужны, для этого давно придумали fseek, и EOF вообще не нужен, есть SEEK_END который везде разный от библиотеки к библиотеки.

```
#include <stdio.h>
.....
FILE* f;
f = fopen("data", "r");
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
long file_size = ftell(f);
```

Comment: Это, конечно, хорошо, но на вопрос не отвечает